# Can I play overwatch with a keyboard and mouse on Xbox?

Tags: overwatch

I'm getting a new keyboard and mouse soon and, I'm wondering if I can play overwatch with it.

Answer (score 2):

After some reading on various forums, it seems that despite Blizzard having previously stated that they are not in favor the idea of KB+M on console, there seems to be plenty of videos on youtube showing that there are in fact players using KBM through the use of 3rd party adapters.

In other words, while Overwatch on Xbox appears to be KBM-compatible through the use of 3rd party tools, it seems unclear whether it's oficially allowed. Just make sure you actually skim through the documents and see if it's cheating before clicking "I agree".

Comment: The XBox supports using keyboard and mouse directly without an adapter, but Overwatch directly ignores it as an input device. As a hack, people use these adapters to let them use a keyboard and mouse by translating the signals. The adapters see the keyboard as gamepad buttons and the mouse as a joystick, so it allows people to effectively "cheat" Blizzard's preferences.